# Return type issue when returning observable's value

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I am new to RxJs (typescript) and don't know much about **Observables**. I have an HTTP call as:

```
// HomeApi.ts
public getTypes(): Observable<Array<KeyValueModel>> {
  return this.request('GET', Url).pipe(map((Res) => Res.data));
}
```

This returns an `Observable`.

I am subscribing the api call in a service as:

```
// service.ts
get Types() { // <---- Getting return type error
  HomeApi.getTypes().subscribe((Res) => {
    return Res;
  });
}
```

But I am getting `A 'get' accessor must return a value.ts(2378).`

I also used a function instead, which returns `void` as:

```
// service.ts
public getTypes() { // <---- Getting return type as void
  HomeApi.getTypes().subscribe((Res) => {
    return Res;
  });
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't possibly transform an asynchronous call into a synchrnous one. Return the observable. Subscribe to it in the component, or in its view. The return yu have in Types() doesn't return from the getter. It returns from the callback function passed to subscribe().